Facebook Open Graph not working; no previews
I'm having problems with my OG tags in Facebook debugger. It is displaying properly in , however Facebook Open Graph returned with a Bad Response Code: URL returned a bad HTTP response code 503.
Facebook debugger
https://www.entertainmentvandaag.nl/
I changed robots.txt and allowed "FacebookBot" explicit, but nothing changed.

Your server returns a 503 using an http viewer when a request is sent using Facebook’s user agent, but is okay with a regular browser user agent (200 response). Your server logs might provide some information as to what’s happening. A separate issue is your page has a large (38kb) CSS section right at the start and your server doesn’t support Accept-Ranges. It might be good to move the CSS to below the og/twitter meta data.

Thanks for your reply. I've tried to move the css below og/twitter. Afterwards I opened the error logs and found multiple times >> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get() in

Check online for solutions to WordPress problems with a call to undefined…  It could be related to some plugin you’re using.

I've disabled a couple of plugins and the error dissapapeared. But then two new errors came in its place :(
[client 2a01:238:200::] Script timed out before returning headers: wp-cron.php
13.08.2024 16:32:49 entertainmentvandaag.nl [client 2a01:238:200::] AH01220: Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /home/strato/http/premium/rid/91/69/512219169/htdocs/STRATO-apps/wordpress_01/app/wp-cron.php
I've searched the internet for a solution but haven't found it yet.
